# How to modify timezone of a datetime field before saving into database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

As Rails by default stores datetime in UTC format, i want to change the timezone format from UTC to another and then save it to database.

I have created a new `<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :class => :timezone %>` field in my form where a user can select the timezone along with date time.

Before saving into database, i want to convert this `datetime` column into `:time_zone` format as user has selected.

Existing code in controller, but not working:

```
  def create
    @obj = User.new(params[:user]) 
    @obj.start_date.in_time_zone(@obj.time_zone)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @obj.save
       --------
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
Time.getlocal(time_zone)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-getlocal

It seems like it would do what you want as far as converting a utc time to a local time in any timezone.

Then you could skip the conversion to utc on the save via :

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:written_on]
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html